# How to create a private cloud using openstack for file sharing

Tags: ftp, cloud, openstack

I wish to create a private cloud using openstack for our college (which has to be hosted in our college) which will be mostly used for file sharing purpose (right now we have this as one of the priority) so that students can access the files hosted on it from their home.

Right now I have installed openstack's latest version in my local ubuntu machine (All in one machine)using devstack for the testing purpose, it's working fine. Now I am planning to install multi node open stack with help of my friend's laptops (3-4 laptops) to host files which can be accessed through FTP or HTTP. Once configured with local machines we will replicate the same in our college environment. At this moment I am not able to understand what all components are required to be installed and what should be the openstack structure to achieve our requirement.

Please let me know how should I proceed for the same.

Comment: I think you got it all wrong from the start. Openstack is middle-ware to provide virtualized environment. Since you only need the functionality of file sharing there are other solutions to consider. For example you can built a storage cluster using GlusterFS and then mount the that storage to an owncloud server which will be used to provide the means for sharing.

Comment: Still we are confused about the Openstack. Can we get some documentation or guide for the openstack.
and if we are going thru OWNCLOUD then what is the need of OPENSTACK

Comment: Thats what I am talking about, for file sharing you do not need openstack.